# set default value for date time parameter in rdlc

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, rdlc, reportviewer, rdl

i have a report which has extension of rdl (Microsoft Reporting Services Projects) in visual studio 2017 and this report has a date time parameter

i want to set a default value for this parameter as current date in order not to force a user to choose a value for this parameter

so when i right click the parameter i choose Default Values then Specify Values 
then i add the Value =Now()

with no benefit when i preview the report the date time parameter becomes disabled

how to enter a default value as current date without time  value

Comment: The method, as you've described it, should work. I've just tried it and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Your only question seems to be:

> How to enter a default value as current date without time value?

To do this, rather than using `=now()` which returns the current date and time, you can use `=today()` which returns just today's date.

Comment: that's what i'am wondering if a put a fixed value Example 7/10/2018 it works but when i add an expression value like =now() or = today() parameter becomes disabled at preview

Comment: because previous way which is putting =today() as default value is not working with me i have applied the following solution as alternative way : i got  default values from a query  and my query was a dataset that has the statement :SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate()) AS CurrentDate and it worked for me